# While loop output multiple value comparison and echo message if different

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop

I have a loop setup to feed in a file with a list of IP's. The loop will search through a file using the IP's to get the associated MAC address. Sometimes for each IP there will be more than one MAC listed for it. It could be one or it could be seven or more. That is really an unknown. All I know is I need to be able to compare how ever many MAC's are reported for each IP and echo something if they do not all match. Here is what my script output looks like now:

```
Testing 192.168.17.25
00:0f:XX:41:e7:50; 00:0f:XX:41:e7:50; 00:0f:XX:41:e7:50; 
Testing 192.168.17.26
00:0f:XX:43:7a:f0; 00:0f:XX:43:7a:f0; 00:0f:XX:43:7a:f0; 00:0f:XX:43:7a:f0;
```

And here is my while loop:

```
cat $list | while read line;

do
echo "Testing $line"
var=$(/bin/grep -A 10 -w $line $file | /bin/grep 'ethernet' | /bin/awk '{print  $3}')
echo $var

done
```

How can I construct an if/then to go inside the loop to compare the MAC addresses and echo a message if it finds one that is different?

UPDATE: The $list file is a simple text file with IP's.

192.168.17.1

192.168.17.2

etc...

The $file I am running the IP's through to get the MAC is a DHCP lease file.

```
lease 192.168.17.28 {
starts 2 2016/07/12 07:36:15;
ends 3 2016/07/13 07:36:15;
tstp 3 2016/07/13 07:36:15;
tsfp 3 2016/07/13 19:36:15;
atsfp 3 2016/07/13 19:36:15;
cltt 2 2016/07/12 07:36:15;
binding state free;
hardware ethernet 84:7b:eb:24:87:ef;
uid "\001\204{\353$\207\357";
```

UPDATE: @ pakistanprogrammerclub

When I run the script I get:

```
[root@localhost]# ./genipmacs.sh < leasesfile > ipmaclist
awk: cmd. line:2: {ipmac[$1][$2]=1}
awk: cmd. line:2:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:6:     for(mac in ipmac[ip])
awk: cmd. line:6:                     ^ syntax error
```

Not sure what its wanting here. Does something else need to be enclosed in quotes?

UPDATE #2 @ pakistanprogrammerclub

After using the modified awk code the script runs as expected no errors. However, my ipmaclist file looks like this:

```
 192.168.17.25 1       00:0
 00:0    4164    192.168.17.26
 192.168.17.27    1       192.168.17.28
 00:0    4164    192.168.17.29   192.168.17.30
```

Its not getting the MAC for some reason. I think I just need to tweak the grep and sed commands in the code. That seems to be the root cause. Running those outside the script yields the data you see above, then awk tries to parse it. Grep and sed outside script:

```
x.x.x.x x.x.x.x.  00:0
x.x.x.x.    00:0
x.x.x.x.  48:
x.x.x.x x.x.x.x  48:
x.x.x.x.   00:0
```

It seems to be getting the write line just cutting off the mac.

UPdate #3

New ipmaclist content:

```
00:0f:94:43:fd:d0       2       x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x.   1       dc:37:14:82:a2:82
x.x.x.x.  1       00:0f:94:41:d4:d0
x.x.x.x 1       00:0f:94:41:9f:e0
```

Leases file -

```
x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x
```

UPDATE 4

New code also works but in reverse fashion.

```
00:0f:94:c1:31:20       1       192.168.17.26
00:0f:94:c1:1f:30       3       192.168.17.27   192.168.17.28  192.168.17.29
00:0f:94:66:84:f0       1       192.168.17.30
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the format your original file is in?

Comment: Yes give me a few. Just updated.

Comment: Why not make `var` an ***indexed array*** and add `| sort -u` after `/bin/awk '{print  $3}'`, e.g. `var=( $(your stuff | sort -u) )` Then `${#var[@]}` tells you how many unique macs you have and `echo "${var[@]}"` lists them or you could do `for i in ${var[@]}; do echo "$i"; done`.

Comment: That's kind of what I ended up doing. I kept everything the same, except I added the sort -u to the end of my var variable. Now I know if I see more than one MAC, I have an duplicate IP's. .

Comment: The error you show in the question is from `awk` telling you it does not know what `[...][...]` means. A multi-dimensional array in `awk` is used with `[..., ...]`. Also, you fail to show us that part of the code.

Comment: gawk 4.0 has multidimensional arrays - what does awk --version say?

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.7 - I copied the code into my script file exactly like it was written in the answer. So,its identical.

Comment: Can you provide some test data from the leases file?

Comment: I see the problem - I missed MAC hex digits - fixed solution below

Comment: one way the output can be reversed is if the leases file does not have a lease IP line then a MAC line - maybe the first IP is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looping through them by hand, consider using `sort -u` to remove duplicates and then `wc -l` to count.

```
unique_mac_addrs() {
     # First, split them up to individual lines, stripping out
     # any stray spaces or blank lines, then sort and count.
     echo "$@" | tr \; $'\n' | awk '$1{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l
}
sample1="00:0f:XX:43:7a:f0; 00:0f:XX:43:7a:f0; 00:0f:XX:43:7a:f0; 00:0f:XX:43:7a:f0;"
sample2="00:0f:XX:43:7a:f0; FF:0f:XX:43:7a:f0; EE:0f:XX:43:7a:f0; 00:0f:XX:43:7a:f0;"
unique_mac_addrs $sample1  # => 1
unique_mac_addrs $sample2  # => 3
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more in detail on this because you lost me. The loop is how I get the MAC and in your example I am not seeing the file referenced.

Comment: This was intended to come after what you already had instead of an inner loop written in bash. In other words, once you've already got the code in your question generating lines that look like my `sample` lines, you can use my function to postprocess them into a result.

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses gawk 4.0 to generate a tab-separated list of MACS and count for each IP from the lease file - call it ipmacslist:

```
10.0.1.1        1       00:11:22:33:44:55
10.0.1.2        2       00:11:22:33:44:56       00:11:22:37:44:56
10.0.1.3        1       00:11:22:33:44:57
```

You can grep ipmacslist for your list of IPs in $list then filter on the count:

```
grep -F -f$list ipmacslist|awk '$2 > 1'
```

Here's the code to generate ipmacslist - this is a pipeline - put it in a script say genipmacs.sh and feed it the lease file contents on stdin - `./genipmacs.sh <leasefile.leases >ipmacslist`

```
# grep ip and mac from lease file
grep -Po '^lease \K[0-9.]*|hardware ethernet \K[0-9:a-f]*'|
# join pairs of consecutive lines to get ip-mac pair on one line
sed -n 'N; s/\n/\t/;p'|
# collect unique ip-mac pairs - output ip unique macs list and count
# uses gawk 4.0 2D arrays
awk '
# bail on invalid input
!/^[0-9.]+\t[0-9:a-f]+/ {
  printf("error line %d not IP-MAC pair: \"%s\"\n", NR, $0)
  exitstatus=1
  exit exitstatus
}
{ipmac[$1][$2]=1}
END {
  if(exitstatus) exit exitstatus
  for(ip in ipmac) {
    printf("%s\t%d", ip, length(ipmac[ip]))
    for(mac in ipmac[ip])
      printf("\t%s", mac)
    printf("\n")
  }
}
'
```

Comment: I do not see anything in the code that tells it where to find my lease file? And in your grep command, what is the $list variable?

Comment: $list is your own variable with the file containing list of IPs to check - the code is a pipeline - feed it the lease file contents on stdin - you can modify it to read the lease file in other ways too

Comment: Ok. I'm getting some errors when I run the script. I'll update my post to add the error.

Comment: I'm not sure my version of awk supports your awk code. I'm on GNU Awk 3.1.7. Can you modify your answer if needed to reflect how the awk code would look like to get the same result for GNU Awk 3.1.7?

Comment: posted new solution - hope it works with your version

Answer (score 1):

Pre-gawk 4.0 solution uses fake 2D array - this was painful - please please upgrade to gawk 4.0 - it is already a few years old -

```
# grep ip and mac from lease file
grep -Po '^lease \K[0-9.]*|hardware ethernet \K[0-9:a-f]*'|
# join pairs of consecutive lines to get ip-mac pair on one line
sed -n 'N; s/\n/\t/;p'|
# collect unique ip-mac pairs - output ip unique macs list and count
awk '
# bail on invalid input
!/^[0-9.]+\t[0-9:a-f]+/ {
  printf("error line %d not IP-MAC pair: \"%s\"\n", NR, $0)
  exitstatus=1
  exit exitstatus
}
{
  if(($1, $2) in ipmac) next
  if($1 in macs) {
    macs[$1]=macs[$1] "\t" $2
  } else {
    ips[i++]=$1
    macs[$1]=$2
  }
  ++nmacs[$1]
  ipmac[$1, $2]=1
}
END {
  if(exitstatus) exit exitstatus
  for(i=0; i < length(ips); ++i) {
    ip=ips[i]
    printf("%s\t%d", ip, nmacs[ip])
    printf("\t%s\n", macs[ip])
  }
}
'
```

Its output and a test leases file follow

```
10.0.1.1        1       00:11:22:33:44:55
10.0.1.2        2       00:11:22:33:44:56       00:11:22:37:4f:56
10.0.1.3        2       00:11:22:33:44:57       00:11:22:a3:44:57
```

test leases file

```
lease 10.0.1.1 {
  starts 5 2015/05/15 01:57:17;
  ends 5 2015/05/15 02:07:17;
  tstp 5 2015/05/15 02:07:17;
  cltt 5 2015/05/15 01:57:17;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:11:22:33:44:55;
  client-hostname "host1";
  uid "foo";
}
lease 10.0.1.2 {
  starts 5 2015/05/15 02:09:16;
  ends 5 2015/05/15 02:19:16;
  tstp 5 2015/05/15 02:19:16;
  cltt 5 2015/05/15 02:09:16;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:11:22:33:44:56;
  client-hostname "host2";
  uid "bar";
}
lease 10.0.1.3 {
  starts 5 2015/05/15 02:16:01;
  ends 5 2015/05/15 02:26:01;
  tstp 5 2015/05/15 02:26:01;
  cltt 5 2015/05/15 02:16:01;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:11:22:33:44:57;
  client-hostname "host3";
  uid "baz-1";
}
lease 10.0.1.3 {
  starts 5 2015/05/15 02:17:01;
  ends 5 2015/05/15 02:27:01;
  tstp 5 2015/05/15 02:27:01;
  cltt 5 2015/05/15 02:17:01;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:11:22:a3:44:57;
  client-hostname "host3";
  uid "baz-2";
}
lease 10.0.1.2 {
  starts 5 2015/05/15 02:09:16;
  ends 5 2015/05/15 02:19:16;
  tstp 5 2015/05/15 02:19:16;
  cltt 5 2015/05/15 02:09:16;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:11:22:37:4f:56;
  client-hostname "host2";
  uid "bar-1";
}
```

Comment: added hex digits for MAC pattern

Comment: Yep. that did it. However, now when I run the grep command - grep -F -f$list ipmacslist|awk '$2 > 1'. It exits and returns nothing. My actual command looks like this - grep -F -f leases ipmaclist|awk '$2 > 1' - where "leases" is the list of IP addresses. That file data is arranged in a single column, with nothing but IP's.

Comment: Should the content of ipmaclist look like the format you showed in your original answer? Because mine does not. I will update my post.

Comment: can you post a few lines from both ipmaclist and leases files?

Comment: I just updated my post with the information you asked for.

Comment: Try my test leases file like so ./genipmacs.sh <testleasesfile and see if you get the same output as I posted

Comment: It does so there is something about the my leases file that is different. I know its a dynamic file and not all lease records will be listed like your test lease file. But I dont think that should matter since we are only looking for certain patterns.

Comment: I put a sample lease record of my leases file in my original post. I wonder if you take that and create some multiple entries if you would get the same results I get.

Comment: alright - let's try this one more time - I made some changes to the script

Comment: Close - but its reversed. The MAC's are listed first, then the IP's. Will update post to show output.